# CSS Lower Specificity Rule Overrides Higher Specificity

Tags: html, css

I am in the middle of an online web development course right now and have been building a few webpages to learn HTML and CSS. In this particular. My problem is that in the page, the font-family rules from my p and h3 element type style rules are overriding font-family rules from specific ID selectors. I was able to work around the issue by chaining selectors, but I don't understand why it was happening in the first place.

This is the bit of the HTML I'm try to format:

```css
h3 {
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 24px;
}

p {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
}

.font-container {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 45%;
}

.caps {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

#helvetica{
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#roboto{
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
}

#lora{
  font-family: "Lora", serif;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <h2>Fonts</h2>

    <div class="font-container" id="helvetica">
        <h3>Helvetica</h3>
        <div class="normal">
            <p>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.</p>
            <p><em>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.</em></p>
            <p><strong>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.</strong></p>
        </div>
        <div class="caps">
            <p>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.</p>
            <p><em>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.</em></p>
            <p><strong>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.</strong></p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="font-container" id="roboto">
        <h3>Roboto</h3>
        <div class="normal">
            <p>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.</p>
            <p><em>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.</em></p>
            <p><strong>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.</strong></p>
        </div>
        <div class="caps">
            <p>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.</p>
            <p><em>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.</em></p>
            <p><strong>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.</strong></p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="font-container" id="lora">
        <h3>Lora</h3>
        <div class="normal">
            <p>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.</p>
            <p><em>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.</em></p>
            <p><strong>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.</strong></p>
        </div>
        <div class="caps">
            <p>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.</p>
            <p><em>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.</em></p>
            <p><strong>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.</strong></p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Inspecting with Chrome DevTools indicates that the font-family for all the text in this div is being inherited from the p and h3 rules. Can somebody explain why this is happening?

Comment: when you set the rule on the parent element (`<div id="...">') you are relying on the fact that the children will use the `inherit` value. Setting the values directly over the `<h3>` elements will override that `inherit` value, and the rule on the parent will loose its effects here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`#helvetica`, `#lora` & `#roboto` only applies to any character without html tag within the `div` tag. Because you 'wrap' Helvetica with h3 tag, and you have **h3 css rules**, it will replace `#helvetica` rules that applies to `div` tag.

see my [example](https://codepen.io/mshafrizal/pen/YzGOVrq)

```html
<div class="container">
  <h2>Fonts</h2>

    <div class="font-container" id="helvetica">
        <h3>Helvetica</h3>
        This text will inherit from #helvetica rules
        <div class="normal">
            <p>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.</p>
            <p><em>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.</em></p>
            <p><strong>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.</strong></p>
        </div>
        <div class="caps">
            <p>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.</p>
            <p><em>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.</em></p>
            <p><strong>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.</strong></p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="font-container" id="roboto">
        <h3>Roboto</h3>
        This text will inherit from #roboto rules  
        <div class="normal">
            <p>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.</p>
            <p><em>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.</em></p>
            <p><strong>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.</strong></p>
        </div>
        <div class="caps">
            <p>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.</p>
            <p><em>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.</em></p>
            <p><strong>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.</strong></p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="font-container" id="lora">
        <h3>Lora</h3>
        This text will inherit from #lora rules
        <div class="normal">
            <p>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.</p>
            <p><em>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.</em></p>
            <p><strong>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.</strong></p>
        </div>
        <div class="caps">
            <p>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.</p>
            <p><em>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.</em></p>
            <p><strong>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.</strong></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
h3 {
font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 24px;
}

p {
    font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
}

.font-container {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 45%;
}

.caps {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

#helvetica{
    font-family: 'Helvetica', sans-serif;
}

#roboto{
    font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
}

#lora{
    font-family: "Lora", serif;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add separate css for `h3` and p `tag`

```css
h3 {
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 24px;
}

p {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
}

.font-container {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 45%;
}

.caps {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

#helvetica,
#helvetica h3,
#helvetica p{
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#roboto,
#roboto h3,
#roboto p{
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
}

#lora,
#lora h3,
#lora p{
  font-family: "Lora", serif;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <h2>Fonts</h2>

    <div class="font-container" id="helvetica">
        <h3>Helvetica</h3>
        <div class="normal">
            <p>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.</p>
            <p><em>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.</em></p>
            <p><strong>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.</strong></p>
        </div>
        <div class="caps">
            <p>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.</p>
            <p><em>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.</em></p>
            <p><strong>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.</strong></p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="font-container" id="roboto">
        <h3>Roboto</h3>
        <div class="normal">
            <p>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.</p>
            <p><em>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.</em></p>
            <p><strong>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.</strong></p>
        </div>
        <div class="caps">
            <p>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.</p>
            <p><em>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.</em></p>
            <p><strong>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.</strong></p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="font-container" id="lora">
        <h3>Lora</h3>
        <div class="normal">
            <p>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.</p>
            <p><em>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.</em></p>
            <p><strong>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.</strong></p>
        </div>
        <div class="caps">
            <p>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.</p>
            <p><em>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.</em></p>
            <p><strong>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.</strong></p>
        </div>
    </div>
```